# Address of returned instance variable vs returning address of instanced variable

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

If I have and arbitrary class:

```
class myClass {
public:
    int * getAddress() {
        return &myVar;
    }

    int getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
private:
    int myVar;

};
```

Let's say I want to store the address of my variable inside another class. What is the difference if doing

`int * address = myClassInstance.getAddress()` and

`int * address = &myClassInstance.getMyVar()`

I assumed that both of these will give me the same value. Can someone explain what exactly is happening here.

What I'm assuming is happening right now is that my instance variable isn't actually being returned but instead a copy of the value is being returned so when I try to access its address I'm really accessing a random address which will no longer be valid outside the scope of the function call.

Comment: The second should not compile on a standards compliant compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza — the standard does not require compilers to refuse to compile that code. It requires compilers to issue a diagnostic.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, fair enough. "should not compile without at least issuing a diagnostic".

Comment: @juanchopanza actually it compiles using VS 2015

Comment: @Archmede Yes, that is a non-standard compiler "extension". You can probably find a setting to force VS to be more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right. The first is valid address of the member. The second is 'random' stack address to the temporary value created, well, on the stack. Noteworthy is fact, that if you change:

```
int getMyVar() {
    return myVar;
}
```

To

```
int &getMyVar() {
    return myVar;
}
```

code `int * address = &myClassInstance.getMyVar()` is completelly valid and yields the same result as `int * address = myClassInstance.getAddress()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.

When you call `myClassInstance.getMyVar()` it doesn't return the `myVar` variable itself, but a copy of its value.

`&myClassInstance.getMyVar()` is invalid, because you are not allowed to take the address of a temporary copy (that would be useless because it would be destroyed immediately and then you'd have the address of nothing).

Comment: Actually, as references are pointers under the hood, you can take address of the temporary using rvalue references.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
int * address = myClassInstance.getAddress();
```

you get an address of `myVar` member calling `getAddress()` method. After that `address` contains an address of `myVar` member. So far, so good.

However, in the second case:

```
int * address = &myClassInstance.getMyVar();
```

`getMyVar()` returns a temporary `int`, which is a copy of `myVar`. Then you try to get an address of this *temporary*, not `myVar`, which should produce a [compilation error](https://godbolt.org/g/PSdHWg).